# Is there a JSON equivalent of xsd.exe?

Tags: .net, json, json.net, schema, xsd.exe

I am able to generate an XSDs for MyDataContract.dll assembly using xsd.exe

```
xsd.exe MyDataContract.dll
```

This will generate an schema0.xsd with definitions for all the types in the assembly.

Is there any equivalent for JSON?

I've looked at Newtonsoft Json.NET Schema but this seems to only provide an API, not an executable. Additionally, it seems to work at the 'type' level, without being able to generate a JSON schema for all types in an assembly.

I'd like to generate the JSON schema as part of my CI build.

I suppose I could build a console application using Json.Net Schema with reflection, etc. to achieve this, but it surprising no such program already exists.

Comment: Why not convert the xsd to json in an additional step? https://github.com/andrewbober/xsd2jsonschema

Comment: Because XSD.exe understands how the .Net XmlSerializer works. Similarly svcutil.exe understands how the DataContractSerializer works, and generates different XSDs to XSD.exe. Really, I want to use JsonSchema.exe to generate my JSON schema files, and JsonConvert for serialization. But JsonSchema.exe does not exist. Converting XSDs to JSON schema files will almost certainly end up with inaccurate schema definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web API project, you could consider adding Swashbuckle, it can generate swagger schema (which is now called OpenAPI I believe) and can generate a nice UI:

On nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/

Specifications:
https://swagger.io/specification/

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Not sure if this helps as you wanted a command line tool.